# Overriding MS Office Hotkeys

Tags: c#

How might I go about programatically overriding hotkeys in MS Office?

I have a global hotkey (**CTRL+SHIFT+1**) for my app that works in other applications but seems to get lost when I try it in any MS Office application. When I shutdown my app the hotkeys work in MS Office again as they are supposed to.

Comment: Why is it relevant to Python, which IDE or compiler did you use, how exactly did you define that global hotkey etc? Presumably you are running under Windows, what version and SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go with SetWindowsHookEx and set dwThreadId to 0.

So you can hook all key input from all thread (by this way, you can make a keylogger..)

please read [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx)

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here in case someone want to view another answer. This also descibes a hook.

It is possible to do this using a keyboard hook. A good hook class for this can be found on this  [CodeProject Article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7294/processing-global-mouse-and-keyboard-hooks-in-c)

Using the below code will prevent the <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> from occurring. You can use this to override whichever keys you'd like.

This will even override hotkeys which you added via `RegisterHotKey` Win API.

Once you have those classes in your project you can add handlers to the static `HookManager` class like below.

```
//It's worth noting here that if you subscribe to the Key_Press event then it will break the international accent keys.
HookManager.KeyPress += HookManager_KeyPress;
HookManager.KeyDown += HookManager_KeyDown;
HookManager.KeyUp += HookManager_KeyUp;
```

You can also add mouse events, but for simplicity I'm just showing the keyboard hook.

I've also created a generic list so that I know which keys are currently down and I remove those keys from the list on the `KeyUp` event.

```
public static List<Keys> keysDown = new List<Keys>();
private static void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            if(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode) == false)
            {
                keysDown.Add(e.KeyCode);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && WIN())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                //Do what you want when this key combination is pressed
            }

        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys
            while(keysDown.Contains(e.KeyCode))
            {
                keysDown.Remove(e.KeyCode);
            }
        }

        private static void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //Used for overriding the Windows default hotkeys

        }

        public static bool CTRL()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RControlKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Control) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ControlKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool SHIFT()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RShiftKey) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.Shift) ||
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.ShiftKey))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool WIN()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.LWin) || 
                keysDown.Contains(Keys.RWin))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool ALT()
        {
            //return keysDown.Contains(Keys.LShiftKey)
            if (keysDown.Contains(Keys.Alt))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```